# rvm install 1.8.7 (snow leopard) make.log error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I'm installing ruby 1.8.7 with rvm on a new macbook pro. I'm on 10.6.8 and I have xcode 4.0.2. RVM is up. I can install 1.9.2 with no problems. But when I try 1.8.7 I get an error:

```
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/brentw/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p352/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

In the make.log file the last few lines read:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../../libruby.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
compiling win32ole
compiling zlib
making ruby
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common    -DRUBY_EXPORT  -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load   main.o  -lruby -lpthread -ldl -lobjc   -o ruby
ld: warning: ignoring file ./libruby.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ruby_init_stack", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_ruby_init", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_ruby_options", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_ruby_run", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/ay/aypnf68iFrumAawnjs+96FjhQuk/-Tmp-//cc7BuLDX.out (No such file or directory)
make[1]: *** [ruby] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've been searching all over the place, trying multiple things but I can't seem to get 1.8.7 up. I tried different patches (though probably not all), tried installing ree instead, installed rvm readline, tried "rvm install 1.8.7 -C --with-arch=x86_64, --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr"... no luck...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I finally downgraded to rvm 1.8.0 and also used the --with-readline-dir flag to install ruby 1.8.7. It finally worked!! Thanks for the clues.

Answer (score 1):

ahh, found the answer here: https://rvm.io/os/darwin/

```
rvm_archflags="-arch i386" CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386" rvm install 1.8.7 --patch osx-arch-fix
```

Now I'm getting a libz problem when I try to install gems.. to be solved..

Comment: This one won't work. The problem is rvm 1.8.2. Roll back rvm to 1.8.0 as described in my answer and everything will work as expected.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling OSX because of this libz problem, and got everything up with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ist rvm 1.8.2. You have to rollback to 1.8.0 and everything will work as expected.

```
rvm get 1.8.0
```

If you have removed rvm, install 1.8.0 with this command:

```
curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm -o rvm-installer ; chmod +x rvm-installer ; ./rvm-installer --version 1.8.0
```

You won't get the zlib error, if you use rvm 1.8.0 and you don't need any flags to install it.

Comment: thanks, that did the job, as a side note, `rvm get 1.8.0` is a much easier way to downgrade! :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all that had to be done, was rvm get head which would have taken you to 1.8.3 which solved the issue by removing an accidently added -arch i386 to the build process. On top of that, simply installing zlib from Homebrew would eliminate the zlib issue as well as doing

```
rvm install 1.8.7 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/x.x.x
```

or if you installed zlib using rvm as 'rvm pkg install zlib'  you could then have done

```
rvm install 1.8.7 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

I believe I've updated the documentation on the site to reflect this. If you find that to be in error, please open an Issue against https://github.com/rvm/rvm-site/issues/ please and I will be more than glad to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a solution, but this what I did when I had this...

I have spent on this issue a lot of time, I ended up grapping and compiling ruby my self and using another ruby version manager called [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), after installing it:

Install readline using home brew:
`brew install readline`

then download latest ruby version like 1.9.2-p290:
http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.gz
and extract it in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/

then go to:

```
cd $HOME/.rbenv/versions
```

then buid the ruby version by doing the following:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/
make
sudo make install
```

Don't forget to set your current version as:

```
rbenv global 1.9.2-p290
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: hmm. Yeah I do need rvm. (thanks though, I can keep that in mind for later). There was a previous user on this computer who had it installed with the versions I need. I installed rvm again (no checking if it was there already), and started doing everything.